# How to fit CSS grid layout items when there is not enough item

Tags: css, layout, css-grid

I'm trying to craft a layout with the CSS grid.
At first, I handled it with grid maker sites, well everything was reliable before I realize that the problem is that: **my layout is not dynamic**.

See the below picture it is what I wanted to do and did it:

[image]

Now when I remove one of the grid children this happens:

[image]

So it is my question: how I can make something that is dynamic?
I mean when I do not have enough items another items be fitted in the wrapper, something like this:

[image]

Comment: CSS-Grid can't do that automatically. That's what flexbox is designed for.

Comment: @Paulie_D you are right but for flex layout i must put left and right side in a wapper, the layout items i needa design should not be in wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grid` allow to combine row and columns, `flex`, is one or the other.

What you can do , is to set the CSS to match different cases :

demo from 5 to one child

```css
html {
  display: grid;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
body {
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.grid {
  width: 40vh;
  height: 20vh;
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  gap: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: tomato;
  counter-reset:divs
}
.grid:nth-child(even) {
  background: crimson;
}
.grid div:before {counter-increment:divs;content:counter(divs)}
.grid div {
  background: gray;
}
.grid div:nth-child(1),
.grid div:nth-last-child(1):nth-child(2) {
  grid-row: span 2;
  grid-column: span 2;
}
.grid div:nth-last-child(1):nth-child(even) {
  grid-column: span 2;
}
.grid div:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(2),
.grid div:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(2) + div {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.grid div:last-child:first-child {
  grid-column: span 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div> 
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div> 
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div> 
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! thank you.